# INSERT query via looped AJAX call not working second time and beyond?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a JS function called `db_input`:

```
function db_input(dataString,x){
    $.ajax({
        url: "custom_scripts/db-input.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.auth==true){
                //alert("success: " + x);
            } else {
                alert(data.error);
                return false;
            }          
        }
    })
}
```

that is passed a JS `var` called `dataString` through a `forloop`:

```
for(x=1;x<=var;x++){
    ...
    var dataString = 'a_var='+ a_var + '&b_var='+ b_var  + '&c_var='+ c_var  + '&d_var='+ d_var  + '&e_var='+ e_var;
    db_input(dataString,x);
}
```

that looks for non-empty, validated, `HTML` input elements and inserts the values into JS variables which are appended to `dataString` each iteration and passed via `AJAX` to a `PHP` script that inserts them into a table in a database:

```
<?php
...
    $a_var=$_POST['a_var'];
    $b_var=$_POST['b_var'];
    $c_var=$_POST['c_var'];
    $d_var=$_POST['d_var'];
    $e_var=$_POST['e_var'];

    $rVal=array("auth" => false, "error" => NULL);

   //connect

   $query="INSERT INTO `db`.`table` (`a_var`, `b_var`, `c_var`, `d_var`, `e_var`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
   $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $a_var, $b_var, $c_var, $d_var, $e_var);
   $stmt->execute();

   $rVal['auth']=true;

   $stmt->close();
   $conn->close();

   echo json_encode($rVal);
...
?>
```

Each `HTML` element are stored in `divs` (some together; some separated) ... the JS validation function (that leads to the loop that calls `db_input`) is called by a `button` `onclick`:

```
<input class="submit" style="float:left; color: #595959;" type="button" value="submit" onclick="validate();" />
```

This works the first time ... depending on how many `divs` are open and validated with non-empty data, the JS loops through and inserts `a_var`, `b_var`, `c_var`, `d_var`, and `e_var` into the database via the `db_input` `ajax` call to the `db-input.php` script ...

The issue is that, while the call appears to complete each time (`success`), data is only inserted into the database the first time or until the page is refreshed ... what'(s)(re) the issue(s)?

Comment: try this, add return true in ajax success if statement

Comment: "  if(data.auth==true)"   You need to do JSON.parse on the 'data' variable that gets passed back from the ajax success function. You won't be able to read auth until you do.

Comment: You have to remember that $.axaj is asynchronous: 1. You're using `x` in the ajax callbacks, by the time the callback fires x is not what it was when you passed it in.  2. Your server may not allow that many simultaneous requests from the same IP/Session at the same time and is halting everything beyond the 1st.

Comment: @BilalUsean tested ... same issue ...

Comment: @eatpeanutbutter if(data.auth==true) is working though ...

Comment: @MaxSorin is there a way to check if that is the case?

Comment: best way is put one test alert above ajax, leave the first success, next time you will check whether the ajax called or not. so we conclude ajax problem or some other problem

Comment: @BilalUsean tried it ... each success call is alerting ...

Comment: You have to clean your var dataString each time you trigger your foor loop, i guess you are saving the old data.

Comment: can you please post your php code that saves the data in to your Db ?

Comment: @JorgeMejia tested ... same issue ...

Comment: try this, echo json_encode($rVal); **change to** echo "green"; in ajax if(data=="green"){return true;}

Comment: second time only you get error means ajax return false in second time, put alert in ajax else condition to ensure, research this perspective you can sort out your issue

Comment: Try use async: false in your  $.ajax request

Comment: @Vincent updated ...

Comment: @JorgeMejia tested ... same issue ...

Comment: PDO's error mode is set to Silent by default, please check if there are any errors in Mysql, set the error mode to `Warning ` state like this,  `$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));`

Comment: try complete after .success() ,complete:  function(data){ }

Comment: @faalbane If you've turned off asyc (please dont do this) and it still stops after 2 insertions, you should post your entire html / jquery.

Comment: I figured it out ... I accidentally cleared one variable (a boolean on the form to '' instead of a default value of 1) ... I'll add additional validation in db-input.php to make sure query is successful as well ... thanks everyone for your help ...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting async to false:

```
function db_input(dataString,x){
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "custom_scripts/db-input.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.auth==true){
                //alert("success: " + x);
            } else {
                alert(data.error);
                return false;
            }          
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Ever.

Comment: @faalbane Could you please just paste your exact variables setting in your JS code?

Answer (score 0):

How about we change the logic to hit the server all of ONE time instead:

```
function db_input(dataStrings){
    $.ajax({
        url: "custom_scripts/db-input.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: dataStrings,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            if(data.auth==true){
                //alert("success: " + x);
            } else {
                alert(data.error);
                return false;
            }          
        }
    })
}
```

...

```
var dataStrings =[];
for(x=1;x<=var;x++){
    dataStrings.push('a_var='+ a_var + '&b_var='+ b_var  + '&c_var='+ c_var  + '&d_var='+ d_var  + '&e_var='+ e_var);    
}

db_input(dataStrings);
```

You'd have to fix the PHP (someone else would have to weigh in there) to accept a list of value-lists but this would be how I would structure the entire process.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out ... I accidentally cleared one variable (a boolean on the form to '' instead of a default value of 1) ... I'll add additional validation in db-input.php to make sure query is successful ... thanks everyone for your help ...